# "gmap is not a function" when using Google's map api

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I looked around for a bit here and have been googleing for hours with no luck. I am trying to get a map to appear using google's map api but i am getting

```
"$("#map_canvas").gmap is not a function http://people.rit.edu/~ctn9382/536/assignment3/ Line 160"
```

as an error. I have the demo working fine but for some reason it isn't working on the site i made. Can anybody tell me whats wrong?

here is the link:
http://people.rit.edu/~ctn9382/536/assignment3/

in order to get to this point you have to click "show results" and then click a hospital's name and it should create a bunch of stuff on the top of the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jQuery.js` and `jQuery-ui.min.js` are both being included twice. The second time you include it, it overwrites all of the previously defined plugins such as `gmap`. Remove the second set of jQuery and jQuery UI script includes and your code should work.

Edit:

Change this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('maps','3',{'other_params':'sensor=false'});
    //google.load('jquery','1.7');
    //google.load('jqueryui','1.8.9');
</script>
```

It is loading a second copy of jquery.

I'm not sure about the first line.

Comment: Hmmm. Im trying but no matter which ones i get rid of it seems there is some complication. which ones should I be taking out. I tried trial and error but no such luck

Comment: Sweet! Thanks..it sorta works now. just something weird is happening with the map. Its likes it there but not

Comment: this has become a new issue so ill have to make another question for it i guess

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin, it helped me resolve the issue in my MVC4 application. The @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") in the <body> section of _Layout.cshtml was overriding/clearing the reference I had in my view. I removed it from my view and put the @Scripts.Render in the <head> section of _layout.cshtml .. problem solved

Comment: How you know I'm including twice? You are genius! I moved the @Scripts.Render("~/bundlers/jquery") to header at _Layout.cshtml so I no need to additional include again in all views. Thanks.